# Lévy's continuity theorem for random vectors

Tags: probability

Is there an analog for [Lévy's continuity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem) for random vectors?

Comment: It holds for vectors too. See e.g. [here](http://theanalysisofdata.com/probability/8_8.html)

Comment: Thank you for answer!